# IE.document.all returns null element vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

Does anyone know why this `ExplorerButton.Click` returns a 424 object reference error on run? HTML modules were correctly imported to be able to read the html related commands:

```
Private Sub Generate_Click()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim ExplorerInput As HTMLInputElement
Dim ExplorerButton As HTMLInputElement

'Loading Page
IE.navigate "https://www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx"
'Show Window
IE.Visible = True
'Wait for loade
WaitIE IE
'Select document
Set IEDoc = IE.document


'Select Button
 Set ExplorerButton = IEDoc.all.Item("FileUpload1")
'Click button
ExplorerButton.Click --> ERROR 424 

End Sub

Sub WaitIE(IE As InternetExplorer)
   'Loop until load
   Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      DoEvents
   Loop
End Sub
```

I indicated the error with --> ERROR 424. I must be miss-referencing the page... When I looked up tutorials like this one http://qwazerty.developpez.com/tutoriels/vba/ie-et-vba-excel/ , which is really well brought about, this is how the reference was adressed and it seemed to work for him (and for me on the page he mentions). So I guess I must be omitting something when defining the button element. Any help much appreciated!

Thanks!
D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an iframe in the page. That's the issue.

You have to first get the iframe element, and then get the document associated with the iframe.

The fileupload button is in that iframe.

```
IE.navigate "https://www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx"
'Show Window
IE.Visible = True
'Wait for loaded
WaitIE IE
'Select document
Set IEDoc = IE.document

 Dim iBox As HTMLIFrame
 Set iBox = doc.all("iframe1")

 Dim iframeDoc As HTMLDocument
 Set iframeDoc = iBox.contentDocument
'Select Button
 Set ExplorerButton = iframeDoc.all.Item("FileUpload1")
'Click button
ExplorerButton.Click --> ERROR 424
```

Comment: That was it thank you so much! Couldn't access the item directly, but through an iframe this does work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've forgotten to declare the IEDoc variable like this :

```
Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
```

Try this and it will work !

Comment: Thanks! I did forget that!